# Modules inherited by child process from parent process in Perl

Tags: perl, exec, child-process, qx

- I am integrating a logging framework to my perl project which has
  around 300 Perl files.
- So I have written a module `Logging.pm` which has overridden `die` ,
  `say` , `warn` functionalities and since `print` cannot be overridden I have tied it my custom handle.
- I have a master script `execute.pl` which executes all the scripts through `system`/`qx`/`exec`.
- I want to include `Logging.pm` in just `execute.pl` and all the
  functionalities of  `Logging.pm` should be availabe in the child
  process executed by execute.pl through `system()` or `qx()` or
  `exec()`.

**Example of Execution:**

```
execute.pl -> system("test1.pl") -> system("test2.pl")
```

So the `test1.pl` and `test2.pl` should pick up the overridden `die/warn/say/print` if I just include `Logging.pm` in `excute.pl`.

As far I know `system/qx/exec` will be OS call and `Logging.pm` won't be available in the child process, is there any way I can achive this as I don't want to edit 300 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sub-processes are entirely separate processes they will not keep any modules loaded by the parent process.

One possibility to solve this is to set the `PERL5OPT` environment variable. This variable can hold extra command line flags for the Perl interpreter. However, this will affect all Perl processes started directly or indirectly by your script, not just those scripts that are part of your project.

To automatically `use Logging`, you'd add `-MLogging` to the `PERL5OPT`. In shell:

```
$ export PERL5OPT="$PERL5OPT -MLogging"
$ ./execute.pl
```

or

```
$ PERL5OPT="$PERL5OPT -MLogging" ./execute.pl
```

or within `execute.pl`:

```
$ENV{PERL5OPT} .= " -MLogging";
```